# XSL Multi Column Switching

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an xml that lists calls made by a customer, which I need to display across two columns. Depending on the number of calls, the list can be in a single page - single column, single page - double column, or multi page - double column.

I have to use basic apace fop and do not have access to antenna house or similar libraries.

When I use for-each I can display the calls, but only on a single column. I cant for the life of me get to double column.

The closest I got to was this video below by @Eliot Kimber, but just could not get around doing it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6pe7KXicpA

I tried using column mod, but that again just list all the calls in a single column

My XML looks like below.

```
<CallsMade fromNumber="987654321">
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456789</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:35:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>00:04:23</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.24</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456790</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:36:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>00:04:24</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.25</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456791</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:37:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>>00:04:25</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.26</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456792</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:38:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>>00:04:26</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.27</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456793</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:39:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>>00:04:27</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.28</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456794</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:40:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>>00:04:28</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.29</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456795</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 15:41:35</DateTime>
        <Duration>>00:04:29</Duration>
        <Cost>$1.30</Cost>
    </CallItem>
    <CallItem>
        <DialledNumber>0123456931</DialledNumber>
        <DateTime>2019-07-15 17:57:34</DateTime>
        <Duration>00:06:45</Duration>
        <Cost>$2.66</Cost>
    </CallItem>
<CallsMade>`
```

XSL that goes multiple pages, but single column is below

```
<fo:block-container start-indent="0mm" left="5mm" width="48%" span="all">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" font-size="5pt" text-align="center" display-align="center" span="all">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(10)"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(15)"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(12)"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(8)"/>
            <fo:table-body font-size="95%" >
                <xsl:for-each select="CallItem">
                    <fo:table-row height="4mm" text-align="center" display-align="center">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="DialledNumber"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="DateTime"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
</fo:block-container>
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me display the list as below

[image]

Comment: "Depending on the number of calls, the list can be in a single page - single column, single page - double column, or multi page - double column": do you have known values for the number at which you want the XSLT to generate different FO results?

Comment: Thanks Martin. The first page has another block which can be 1-n lines. A page can have a maximum of 60 lines, so after 60 lines, next column...after 120 calls next page...

Comment: My FO is not good, but for the XSLT, if you are able to change it and can use XSLT 2 (possible in the Java world easily by using Saxon 9), you can simply use positional grouping to wrap each chunk of 60 lines into its own container and toggle the `span` attribute if you have more than one chunk. I have tried some examples at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1ya7/3 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1ya7/4, there using a lower value than 60 to experiment with your test data. You might want to add a tag for XSL-FO to get some more knowledgeable help on the FO side.

Comment: If you have spanned things before and have no idea where they will end and therefore no idea where your table will start (and by definition how many fit) then you cannot do this without a formatter unless they support extensions like RenderX's flow-section where you can put multi-columns inside other flows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you really just need to know whether you have fewer than 60 `CallItem`.  If fewer than 60, make the table span both columns, and if not, make it span one column.  Normal page breaking will take care of splitting the table across columns and pages.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <fo:root xml:lang="en">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm">
        <fo:region-body column-count="2" margin="36pt" />
      </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CallsMade">
  <fo:block span="all">
    <xsl:value-of select="@fromNumber" />
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block-container>
    <xsl:if test="count(CallItem) &lt; 60">
      <xsl:attribute name="span">all</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" font-size="5pt" text-align="center" display-align="center" span="all">
      <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(10)"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(15)"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(12)"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(8)"/>
      <fo:table-body font-size="95%" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CallItem" />
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CallItem">
  <fo:table-row height="4mm" text-align="center" display-align="center">
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="DialledNumber"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="DateTime"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="Duration"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```